# Drive a 12v indicator lamp/LED from AC mains

Tags: power-supply, mains, low-power

I want to switch a mains input on and off using a latching switch (which is appropriately rated). The switch supports illumination via a packaged LED, driven by 12V, either AC or DC. The current draw of the packaged LED is tiny: 6mA.

What is a good (power efficient, low part-count) way to generate the 12v (either AC or DC) supply from the AC mains input? There are many solutions in the 1amp+ range, but I wonder if there is some easier solution for this application? I can find all-in-one Buck converter modules but again they're in the 1 or 2A range which seems overkill to drive 6mA. But they are cheap and simple to install.

[The switch](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7452556/)
[The indicator lamp](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/0225997/)

Comment: cheap and simple sounds OK if they are designed to withstand lightning surges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moderate size capacitor will provide an AC current.

Consider 0.047 uF.

Notice this current will **NOT** be isolated.

For 6 milliAmps, you need 1/0.006 = 160 ohms per volt.

If your input voltage is 160 volts peak (about right for 120 Vrms), your impedance should be 160 * 160 = 256 * 10 * 10 = 25,600 ohms.

A 1uF capacitor at 1MHz has reactance (impedance) of -j 0.159 ohms. This is just 1/(2 * pi).

At 100 Hz, the reactance is 10,000X higher, or 1,590 ohms.

At 60Hz, about 2,000 ohms. (getting closer)

Thus 0.1 uF produces 10X the reactance, or 20,000 ohms.

And I'll let you chose the final capacitor value. A 0.068 or 0.047 should be good. I don't know if 0.068 uF is stocked in HIGH VOLTAGE models.

===================

Note the comment of Tony_Stewart about SURVIVING LIGHTENING. Thus a simple capacitor, rated 400 volts, is not adequate.

- I've seen 470 ohms at large sizes (1 watt size, for arc_over prevention) used in series with the capacitor.
- And a spark_gap laid out on the PCB.

===========================================

regarding the comment/question of switching at peak of voltage, there is INDUCTANCE in the wiring. 100uH (about 100 meters of wire, or some unknown transformer secondary inductance) has this current:

- 100uH, 100volts

Using V = L * dI/dT and re-arranging, you get the equation

- dI/dT = V / L = 100 volts / 100 uH = 1 amp/uS risetime

How fast will the capacitor charge? Using Q = C * V = I * T, we have

T = C * V / I = 0.047 uF * 100v / 1amp = 4.7 uS to charge the capacitor

This linear model ignores any ringing of the 100uH and the 0.047uF.

Comment: What happens if the supply is switched on at peak mains?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to buy an integrated mini switched-mode power supply, such as [this](https://nl.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/1359268/), which is only 6 euros at RS and has a max output current of 80 mA.

Otherwise, what about just using a resistor? If you put the lamp in series with a 38 kOhm resistor wouldn't that give you the right current for the lamp? (assuming your mains is 240VAC)

Comment: That will dissipate ~1.5W plus power all the time, though, right? 6mA * (240-12)V

Comment: But, the embedded SMPS modules look a good option: especially from a safety POV.

Comment: Yeah the resistor option isn't great, only from a simplicity point of view. You could put a few small resistors in series to get the required power dissipation, or you can get a 2W power resistor around that value.